# Create object with foreach inside object

Tags: javascript, object

There's the "options" method where I send an object as parameter and I want this object to be stored in the variable `answer`. The code is:

```
var Selectable = {
    create: function(type) {
        Object.create(this);
        this.type = type;
        this.id =  Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substring(0, 5);

        this.cacheDom();
        return this;
    },
    cacheDom: function(){
        this.$target = $('#selectable-target');
        this.$id = $('#selectable-' + this.id);
        this.$options = this.$id.find('.selectable-options');
        this.$revise = this.$id.find('a.revise');
    },
    options: function(values){
        this.answers = {};
        Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {
            this.answers[key] = values[key];
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$target.append(
            $('<div>')
            .attr('id', 'selectable-'+this.id)
            .append(
                $('<div>')
                .addClass('selectable-options')
            )
        )

        this.cacheDom();
    }
};
```

As instantiate and try to insert the object in the console into the answers property, I get this:

```
var test = Selectable.create('img');
undefined

test.options({'foo': '1', 'foo2': '0'});
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'foo' of undefined(…)
```

To solve the problem I could just copy the object to the property like this:

```
options: function(values){
            this.answers = values;
}
```

I want to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: If a function is called without `new` operator (or `apply` and `call` methods), the object `this` will be the global window object. This is what is happening when you call `Selectable.create()`

Comment: @jcbp: No. `Selectable.create()` calls the `create` function with `Selectable` for `this` - it's a method call!

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in

```
Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {
  this.answers[key] = values[key];
});
```

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you'll see that, when using `forEach`, `this` is `undefined` in the callback, unless you pass a custom argument. The solution is to rewrite it as follows:

```
Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {
  this.answers[key] = values[key];
}, this);
```

The change forces the value `this` in the callback to be equal to the value of `this` in the caller.

Equivalently, but ES6 only, you can use `=>` instead of `function`, which captures `this`, and was a bit faster last time I checked (which was at least 1 year ago):

```
Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
  this.answers[key] = values[key];
});
```

Comment: If you were using ES6, you'd do `this.answers = Object.assign({}, values)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand what is Object and which 'this' belong to which instance. In following piece of code :

```
1 options: function(values){ // outer function
2     this.answers = {};
3     Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) { // inner function
4         this.answers[key] = values[key];
5     });
6 },
```

First 'this' (2nd line) - linked to outer function instance. But second 'this' - linked to inner function. More than that - no one of 'this'-es not linked to Selectable.

To solve such mess - firstly you have to introduce the object as a function.

```
var Selectable = function() {
```

Than save 'this' inside some variable.

```
var that = this;
```

Than use 'that' instead of 'this' inside all your inner functions.

Finally, use Selectable like this:

```
var selectable = new Selectable();
selectable.options({'foo':'bar'});
```

Hope it helps